# React render component after array finished rendering

Tags: reactjs, render

I am making an api call on componentDidMount the problem is that the api takes some seconds to responde in the meanwhile the user could choose to go to another page 
doing so another request is made, if this happens the app crashes. How do fix this issue? for the fix I just need to render the pagination component only when all the array is rendered how do I do so?

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Episode from "../components/Episode";

import "react-virtualized/styles.css"; // only needs to be imported once
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import ButtonBase from "@material-ui/core/ButtonBase";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";
import Like from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import NextButton from "@material-ui/icons/NavigateNext";
import PreviousButton from "@material-ui/icons/NavigateBefore";

// This example assumes you have a way to know/load this information

const styles = theme => ({
 //styles
});

class SeriesPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      apiToken: "",
      serie: {
        image: "",
        description: "",
        title: "",
        likes: 0,
        type: "",
        apiName: ""
      },
      startEpisode: 1,
      endEpisode: 10,
      episodes: [],
      loaded: false,
      clicked: false,
      enabled: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialize(this.state.startEpisode, this.state.endEpisode);
  }

  initialize = async (startIndex, stopIndex) => {
    await this.getTokenFromApi();
    await this.getSerieDetailsByApiName();
    await this.getEpisodeBySeriesApiNameWithRange(startIndex, stopIndex);
  };

  getTokenFromApi = async () => {
    const data = {
      name: "generateToken",
      param: {
        email: "*",
        pass: "*"
      }
    };
    return fetch("*", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          this.setState({
            episodes: "Network request failed"
          });
          throw Error("Network request failed");
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(content => {
        if (content.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState({
            apiToken: content.response.result.token
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          episodes: "There was an internal error"
        });
        throw error;
      });
  };

  getSerieDetailsByApiName = async () => {
    const data = {
      name: "*",
      param: {
        serieApiName: this.props.match.params.series
      }
    };
    return fetch("*", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.apiToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          this.setState({
            episodes: "Network request failed"
          });
          throw Error("Network request failed");
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json(); //response.json() is resolving its promise. It waits for the body to load
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState(
            {
              serie: responseData.response.result,
              loaded: true
            },
            () => {
              console.log(this.state);
            }
          );
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          episodes: "There was an internal error"
        });
        throw error;
      });
  };

  getEpisodeBySeriesApiNameWithRange = async (startIndex, stopIndex) => {
    const data = {
      name: "*",
      param: {
        serieApiName: this.props.match.params.series,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        stopIndex: stopIndex
      }
    };
    return fetch("*", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.apiToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          this.setState({
            episodes: "Network request failed"
          });
          throw Error("Network request failed");
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json(); //response.json() is resolving its promise. It waits for the body to load
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            episodes: [...prevState.episodes, ...responseData.response.result]
          }));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          episodes: "There was an internal error"
        });
      });
  };

  handleLikeClick = () => {
    if (this.state.clicked) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          clicked: !prevState.clicked,
          serie: {
            ...prevState.serie,
            likes: Number(prevState.serie.likes) - 1
          }
        }),
        () => {
          const data = {
            name: "removeLikeSerie",
            param: {
              serieApiName: this.state.serie.apiName
            }
          };
          return fetch("*", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.apiToken,
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
            .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                this.setState({
                  episodes: "Network request failed"
                });
                throw Error("Network request failed");
              }
              return response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.setState({
                episodes: "There was an internal error"
              });
            });
        }
      );
    } else {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          clicked: !prevState.clicked,
          serie: {
            ...prevState.serie,
            likes: Number(prevState.serie.likes) + 1
          }
        }),
        () => {
          const data = {
            name: "likeSerie",
            param: {
              serieApiName: this.state.serie.apiName
            }
          };
          return fetch("*", {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.apiToken,
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          })
            .then(response => {
              if (!response.ok) {
                this.setState({
                  episodes: "Network request failed"
                });
                throw Error("Network request failed");
              }
              return response;
            })
            .catch(error => {
              this.setState({
                episodes: "There was an internal error"
              });
            });
        }
      );
    }
  };

  previousPage = () => {
    if (this.state.startEpisode === 11) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          episodes: [],
          startEpisode: prevState.startEpisode - 10,
          endEpisode: prevState.endEpisode - 10,
          enabled: true
        }),
        () => {
          this.initialize(this.state.startEpisode, this.state.endEpisode);
        }
      );
    } else if (this.state.startEpisode > 10) {
      this.setState(
        prevState => ({
          episodes: [],
          startEpisode: prevState.startEpisode - 10,
          endEpisode: prevState.endEpisode - 10
        }),
        () => {
          this.initialize(this.state.startEpisode, this.state.endEpisode);
        }
      );
    }
  };

  nextPage = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => ({
        episodes: [],
        startEpisode: prevState.startEpisode + 10,
        endEpisode: prevState.endEpisode + 10,
        enabled: false
      }),
      () => {
        this.initialize(this.state.startEpisode, this.state.endEpisode);
      }
    );
  };

  renderRow = item => {
    const { classes, headerIsHidden, ...other } = this.props;
    return <Episode key={item.videoId} episode={item} {...other} />;
  };

  // Render your list
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className={classes.serieDetails}>
          {this.state.loaded ? (
            <Paper className={classes.root}>
              <Grid container spacing={16}>
                <Grid item>
                  <ButtonBase className={classes.image}>
                    <img
                      className={classes.img}
                      alt={this.state.serie.title + " Image"}
                      src={this.state.serie.image}
                    />
                  </ButtonBase>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm container>
                  <Grid item xs container direction="column" spacing={16}>
                    <Grid item xs>
                      <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
                        {this.state.serie.title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography gutterBottom>
                        {this.state.serie.description}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography color="textSecondary">
                        <IconButton
                          className={classes.button}
                          className={this.state.clicked ? classes.liked : ""}
                          aria-label="Like this serie"
                          onClick={this.handleLikeClick}
                        >
                          <Like />
                        </IconButton>
                        {this.state.serie.likes}
                      </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Paper>
          ) : (
            ""
          )}
        </div>
        <div className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.innerContent}>
            {this.state.episodes.constructor === String ? (
              this.state.episodes
            ) : (
              <div>
                {this.state.episodes.map(this.renderRow)}
                <div className={classes.pagination}>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="Previous"
                    className={classes.button}
                    onClick={this.previousPage}
                    disabled={this.state.enabled}
                  >
                    <PreviousButton />
                  </IconButton>
                  <IconButton
                    aria-label="Next"
                    className={classes.button}
                    onClick={this.nextPage}
                  >
                    <NextButton />
                  </IconButton>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(SeriesPage);
```

The pagination component is the div with `className={classes.pagination}`
the array is stored in the state

Comment: I don't need to store the data I just have to render the div after all the array is rendered on the screen

Comment: My problem is that the pagination div gets rendered before the array map function finishes and because of this the user could choose to go to the next page and if he chooses to do so the app crashes because the map function is still rendering. I need something like a callback function that gets called when map finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your state a variable called loading which is initially true:

```
state = {
      ...,
      loading: true
}
```

After the response return of getEpisodeBySeriesApiNameWithRange you can setState of loading to be false:

```
 getEpisodeBySeriesApiNameWithRange = async (startIndex, stopIndex) => {
    const data = {
      name: "*",
      param: {
        serieApiName: this.props.match.params.series,
        startIndex: startIndex,
        stopIndex: stopIndex
      }
    };
    return fetch("*", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + this.state.apiToken,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          this.setState({
            episodes: "Network request failed",
            loading: false
          });
          throw Error("Network request failed");
        }
        return response;
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.json(); //response.json() is resolving its promise. It waits for the body to load
      })
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.response.status === 200) {
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            episodes: [...prevState.episodes, ...responseData.response.result],
            loading: false
          }));
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          episodes: "There was an internal error",
          loading: false
        });
      });
  };
```

When you click on nextPage or previousPage setState of loading to be true again:

```
 nextPage = () => {
this.setState(
     prevState => ({
        episodes: [],
        startEpisode: prevState.startEpisode + 10,
        endEpisode: prevState.endEpisode + 10,
        enabled: false,
        loading: true
      }),
      () => {
        this.initialize(this.state.startEpisode, this.state.endEpisode);
      }
    );
  };
```

the previousPage will be the same.

In **render** you will only render the component if the loading is false which mean the data is fetched:

```
{this.state.loading ? null : <div className={classes.content}>
      <div className={classes.innerContent}>
        {this.state.episodes.constructor === String ? (
          this.state.episodes
        ) : (
          <div>
            {this.state.episodes.map(this.renderRow)}
            <div className={classes.pagination}>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="Previous"
                className={classes.button}
                onClick={this.previousPage}
                disabled={this.state.enabled}
              >
                <PreviousButton />
              </IconButton>
              <IconButton
                aria-label="Next"
                className={classes.button}
                onClick={this.nextPage}
              >
                <NextButton />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
   }
```